# Android Studio Out Of Memory Error ViewFlipper

Tags: javascript, android, out-of-memory

First I would like to say please do not mark this as a duplicate as this question is different from most others. I am trying to create an artificial screensaver of sorts. I am trying to accomplish this by creating an activity with a `ViewFlipper`, throwing some pictures in there, and then setting the `flipInterval` to get things rolling. When I try to run this activity, I get an `OutOfMemory` error. Most suggestions say reducing the size of the picture, but that is not possible as the pictures I have already included are a minimum size. Also their total file sizes range from 20kb-70kb. I have a total of six images now, but the more images I load into my application for other activities the fewer pictures I seem to be able to play in my screensaver. Is there some way that I am increase the number of pictures? Maybe calling `.finish()' on other activities? I'm obviously not sure. Any solutions?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please tell the images you used in viewflipper are of same dimension(width and height)?

Comment: @ManishJain all of my images are `1280p` x `720p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this may be useful

```
public class AnimateBackgroundActivity extends Activity{

protected int[] backgroundImages;
protected ImageView mainBackground;
protected boolean isRunning;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    isRunning = true;
    backgroundImages = new int[6];
    backgroundImages[0] = R.drawable.background0;
    backgroundImages[1] = R.drawable.background1;
    backgroundImages[2] = R.drawable.background2;
    backgroundImages[3] = R.drawable.background3;
    backgroundImages[4] = R.drawable.background4;
    backgroundImages[5] = R.drawable.background5;
}

protected void animateBackground()
{
    Runnable animate = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; isRunning; i = (++i % backgroundImages.length)) {
                final int j = i;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mainBackground.
                        setImageResource(
                                backgroundImages[j]);
                    }
                });

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {

                }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread animBackgroundThread = new Thread(animate);
    animBackgroundThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    isRunning = true;
    animateBackground();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    isRunning = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    isRunning = false;
    super.onPause();
}
}


public class InitScreen extends AnimateBackgroundActivity {


private void initImageLoader() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800)
            // default
            // =
            // device
            // screen
            // dimensions
            .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 100).memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(4 * 1024 * 1024)).memoryCacheSize(4 * 1024 * 1024).discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024).discCacheFileCount(1000).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    initImageLoader();

    setContentView(R.layout.inital);
    mainBackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.init_screen_background);
    animateBackground();

}
```

Comment: I can't seem to import `DisplayImageOptions`, `ImageLoaderConfiguration` `LruMemoryCache` or `ImageLoader`